# C# how cancel an executing method

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, thread-safety

I have a delegate method to run a heavy process in my app (I must use MS Framework 3.5):

```
private delegate void delRunJob(string strBox, string strJob);
```

Execution:

```
    private void run()
    {
        string strBox = "G4P";
        string strJob = "Test";

        delRunJob delegateRunJob = new delRunJob(runJobThread);
        delegateRunJob.Invoke(strBox, strJob);
    }
```

In some part of the method `runJobThread`

I call to an external program (SAP - Remote Function Calls) to retrieve data. The execution of that line can take 1-30 mins.

```
private void runJobThread(string strBox, string strJob)
{
    // CODE ...
    sapLocFunction.Call(); // When this line is running I cannot cancel the process
    // CODE ...
}
```

I want to allow the user cancel whole process.

How can achieve this? I tried some methods; but I fall in the same point; when this specific line is running I cannot stop the process.

Comment: You have to use async and await, in combination with a cancellation token.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck, Will that cancel the operation itself, or just cancel the wait, leaving the operation orphaned and running in the background?

Comment: It depends on your code, you have to check the cancellation token inside the long running method and throw task cancelled exception if you see the task is cancelled.

Comment: "Your" code is sapLocFunction.Call(), which does not take a CancellationToken, unless there's an overload.

Comment: @glenebob correct. It should be modified to take the cancellation token as parameter as well. If this is not possible then there is no way to do the cancellation in an elegant way.

Comment: All these solutions use Cancellation Tokens but is only available since MS Framework 4.0 or above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well; I find out a complicated, but effective, way to solve my problem:

a.) I created a "Helper application" to show a notification icon when the process is running (To ensure to don't interfere with the normal execution of the main app):

```
private void callHelper(bool blnClose = false)
{
    if (blnClose)
        fw.processKill("SDM Helper");
    else
        Process.Start(fw.appGetPath + "SDM Helper.exe");
}
```

b.) I created a Thread that call only the heavy process line.

c.) While the Thread is alive I check for external file named "cancel" (The "Helper application" do that; when the user click an option to cancel the process the Helper create the file).

d.) If exists the file; dispose all objects and break the while cycle.

e.) The method `sapLocFunction.Call()` will raise an exception but I expect errors.

```
private void runJobThread(string strBox, string strJob)
{
    // CODE ...

    Thread thrSapCall = new Thread(() =>
    {
        try { sapLocFunction.Call(); }
        catch { /* Do nothing */ }
    });

    thrSapCall.Start();

    while (thrSapCall.IsAlive)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        try
        {
            if (fw.fileExists(fw.appGetPath + "\\cancel"))
            {
                sapLocFunction = null;
                sapLocTable = null;
                sapConn.Logoff();
                sapConn = null;
                canceled = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        finally { /* Do nothing */ }
    }

    thrSapCall = null;

    // CODE ...
}
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using the delegate mechanism you have to study the async and await mechanism. When you understand this mechanism you can move to cancellationtoken.
An example doing both things can be found here :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx

Comment: This is definitely the best answer.

Comment: I'm not sure about his but I don't think this will do what he wants - can he call `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` while the code is waiting for `sapLocFunction.Call()`?

Comment: That call should be within saplocfunction.call method and cancellationtoken should be passed to it. That method too probably needs refactoring to make use of async and await.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to resort to the method [described here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d0bcb415-fb1e-42e4-90f8-c43a088537fb/aborting-a-long-running-task-in-tpl?forum=parallelextensions). Read the post to see why this is a long way from ideal.
Perhaps this might work...

```
private void runJobThread(string strBox, string strJob, CancellationToken token)
{
   Thread t = Thread.CurrentThread;
    using (token.Register(t.Abort))
    {
    // CODE ...
    sapLocFunction.Call(); // When this line is running I cannot cancel the process
    // CODE ...
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of [dnspy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy) exposes a cancel method on nco3.0.

```
    private readonly static Type RfcConnection = typeof(RfcSessionManager).Assembly.GetType("SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcConnection");
    
    private readonly static Func<RfcDestination, object> GetConnection = typeof(RfcSessionManager).GetMethod("GetConnection", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<RfcDestination, object>)) as Func<RfcDestination, object>;
    
    private readonly static MethodInfo Cancel = RfcConnection.GetMethod("Cancel", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);


    object connection = null;
    var completed = true;
    
    using (var task = Task.Run(() => { connection = GetConnection(destination); rfcFunction.Invoke(destination); }))
{  
    try
    {
         completed = task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(invokeTimeout));
    
         if (!completed)
             Cancel.Invoke(connection, null);                            
                                
         task.Wait();
    }
    catch(AggregateException e)
    {
         if (e.InnerException is RfcCommunicationCanceledException && !completed)
             throw new TimeoutException($"SAP FM {functionName} on {destination} did not respond in {timeout} seconds.");
         throw;
    }   
}
```